# MySQL stored procedure returns different results

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've a query that should search through rows in a table, find any row that contains searched term ('dog%' for example), and then return id of related parent (joined from different table). So, I'm grouping results by parent id, then reordering it and finally, putting an limit/offset to get a list of 10 uniqe ids. Query is inside stored procedure, I call it from PHP.

Problem is, I'm often getting different results. Even though IN params are the same, and nothing in database is changed, I can get very different results per request - ids are not the same, there are differences in order, I'm getting duplicated ids in two requests...

This is procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `FIND_VOCABULARY_ID_BY_MEANING`(IN `in_searched_value` varchar(50)
, IN `in_offset` INT)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
        insert into test values (in_searched_value,in_offset);

        SELECT
        v.id
        FROM vocabulary AS v
        LEFT JOIN vocabulary_sense AS vs ON vs.vocabulary_id = v.id
        LEFT JOIN vocabulary_sense_gloss_eng AS vsg ON vsg.sense_id = vs.id
        WHERE vsg.gloss LIKE CONCAT(in_searched_value,'%')
        GROUP BY v.id
        ORDER BY v.calculated_prio DESC     
        LIMIT 10 OFFSET in_offset;
END
```

How do I call it:

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("CALL $procedureToCall('$searchedTerm', $offset)");
```

In PHP I'm logging values (request and then its result) to log file. Here are two different approaches, in each there is five requests:

```
[2016-10-11 13:35:19] CALL FIND_VOCABULARY_ID_BY_MEANING('vulgar', 0)
[2016-10-11 13:35:19] 17141,16446,38334,58166,17121,45822,35328,37553,41185,45832
[2016-10-11 13:35:22] CALL FIND_VOCABULARY_ID_BY_MEANING('vulgar', 10)
[2016-10-11 13:35:22] 46659,51149,53639,55276,56388,95,63900,71780,73935,17134
[2016-10-11 13:35:25] CALL FIND_VOCABULARY_ID_BY_MEANING('vulgar', 20)
[2016-10-11 13:35:25] 83260,97433,17176,103416,111512,135069,147790,38335,159709,38338
[2016-10-11 13:35:27] CALL FIND_VOCABULARY_ID_BY_MEANING('vulgar', 30)
[2016-10-11 13:35:27] 162898,38340,163783,38359,165067,38360,171044,38364,38378,38380
[2016-10-11 13:35:31] CALL FIND_VOCABULARY_ID_BY_MEANING('vulgar', 40)
[2016-10-11 13:35:31] 38384,41163,41211,45832,45833,45837
[2016-10-11 13:35:33] CALL FIND_VOCABULARY_ID_BY_MEANING('vulgar', 50)

[2016-10-11 13:50:38] CALL FIND_VOCABULARY_ID_BY_MEANING('vulgar', 0)
[2016-10-11 13:50:38] 17141,16446,38334,58166,17121,45822,35328,37553,41185,56388
[2016-10-11 13:50:41] CALL FIND_VOCABULARY_ID_BY_MEANING('vulgar', 10)
[2016-10-11 13:50:41] 95,63900,71780,73935,17134,83260,97433,17176,103416,111512
[2016-10-11 13:50:45] CALL FIND_VOCABULARY_ID_BY_MEANING('vulgar', 20)
[2016-10-11 13:50:45] 135069,147790,38335,159709,38338,162898,38340,163783,38359,165067
[2016-10-11 13:50:48] CALL FIND_VOCABULARY_ID_BY_MEANING('vulgar', 30)
[2016-10-11 13:50:48] 38360,171044,38364,38378,38380,38384,41163,41211,45832,45833
[2016-10-11 13:50:50] CALL FIND_VOCABULARY_ID_BY_MEANING('vulgar', 40)
[2016-10-11 13:50:50] 45837,45841,46659,51149,53639,55276
[2016-10-11 13:50:53] CALL FIND_VOCABULARY_ID_BY_MEANING('vulgar', 50)
```

As you can see, 45832 id is send to me twice in first approach (offset 0 and 40). In second approach it exists once, but in offset 30...

Im also logging input params - offset and searchedTerm - in Mysql - there are also correct, consistent with php's generated log above. So why I'm having those diffenreces?? What I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT

I've found that calling procedure directly from MYSQL client (not php) gives me consitent results - but then again, when I call just the plain query:

```
    SELECT
    v.id
    FROM vocabulary AS v
    LEFT JOIN vocabulary_sense AS vs ON vs.vocabulary_id = v.id
    LEFT JOIN vocabulary_sense_gloss_eng AS vsg ON vsg.sense_id = vs.id
    WHERE vsg.gloss LIKE CONCAT('vulgar','%')
    GROUP BY v.id
    ORDER BY v.calculated_prio DESC     
    LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

results are also different (still consitent, I'm getting the same results, but those results differs from query inside procedure)...

EDIT 2

Here is structure of tables used in query:

```
CREATE TABLE `vocabulary` (
    `id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `entry_sequence` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `jlpt_level` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `calculated_prio` MEDIUMINT(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `idx_vocabulary_calculated_prio` (`calculated_prio`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=174912
;


CREATE TABLE `vocabulary_sense` (
    `id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `vocabulary_id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `fk_vocabulary_sense_vocabulary_id` (`vocabulary_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_vocabulary_sense_vocabulary_id` FOREIGN KEY (`vocabulary_id`) REFERENCES `vocabulary` (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=195529
;


CREATE TABLE `vocabulary_sense_gloss_eng` (
    `id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `sense_id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `gloss` TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `vocabulary_sense_gloss_vocabulary_sense_id` (`sense_id`),
    INDEX `vocabulary_sense_gloss_gloss` (`gloss`(255)),
    CONSTRAINT `vocabulary_sense_gloss_eng` FOREIGN KEY (`sense_id`) REFERENCES `vocabulary_sense` (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
AUTO_INCREMENT=317857
;
```

vocabulary is the main entry. vocabulary_sense (one to many) is pointing at it. And vocabulary_sense_gloss_eng (again, one to many) is pointing at vocabulary_sense.

The "calculated_prio" is just an static INT value.

Comment: Can you post some sample data? What is `calculated_prio`?

Comment: @KamranShahid how come? Offset is the same, it shouldn't mess with results in that way...

Comment: Actually i was thinking there was some problem in the clause after where. needed the sample data but glad you have already solved it

Answer (score 0):

Oh damn, I'm so dumb :)

Problem was with sorting, calculated_prio had positive value for first nine rows only, and for rest of them it was just 0. So only first nine rows were in particular order, everything else was random.

Comment: I had a feeling that was it. Glad you figured it out. ;)